# Generate MiniTest Spec for Existing Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Migrations complain that the model already exists when I try to generate an existing Minitest spec for the model.

```
rails generate model User --spec
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score -1):

```
rails generate model User --spec --skip
```